# Supervised Classification: why do we have to sort the validation samples by descending order?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I saw a piece of supervised classification script:

```
var sample = TotalSample.randomColumn('rand')

// ascending order
var train = sample.limit(70, 'rand', true)

// descending order
var validation = sample.limit(30, 'rand', false)
```

Is that necessary? if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

`sample.limit(70, 'rand', true)`, takes the 70 samples with the lowest random column value, and `sample.limit(30, 'rand', false)` take the 30 samples with the highest random column value. As long as you have at least 100 (70+30) samples, it guarantees that your validation samples are not included in your training samples.